# Difference between arguments in setInterval calls

Tags: javascript, setinterval

What's the difference between these setInterval calls and which ones should be used?

```
setInterval("myFunction()",1000)
setInterval("myFunction",1000)
setInterval(myFunction(),1000)
setInterval(myFunction,1000)
```

My guess is that JS uses eval() on the first two (strings) and calls the latter two directly.

Also, I don't understand the difference between the calls with and without parentheses. The ones with parentheses call it directly and then periodically call its return value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct; the first two use `eval` and must be avoided at all costs.

Adding `()` calls the function immediately.

Javascript functions are actually variables that hold functions.
Writing `setInterval(myFunction, 1000)` passes the value of the `myFunction` variable to `setInterval`.
Writing `setInterval(myFunction(), 1000)` will *call* `myFunction`, then pass whatever `myFunction` returns to `setInterval`, just like calling any other function.

Comment: So if I want to use `setInterval` which should start with a call to the given function right away, I use the parentheses. If I don't want to call it right know but in the given time I use it without. Right?

Comment: @Warren: `setInterval(myFunction(), 1000)` only makes sense if `myFunction` returns a different function.  Otherwise, you'll be passing `undefined` to `setInterval`.