# javascript interval in Object

Tags: javascript, object, intervals

i've wrote a snippet which should start counting a number from 1 to 1000 or pre defined.

Because of needing the script mulitple times i thought it would be a great idea to write it as an object and use it mulitiple times. But i get an error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: root is not defined
  (anonymous function)

What did i wrong?

```
     var time = function() {
        var root = this;
        var i=0;
        root.max = 1000;
        root.elm = false;
        root.runTime = function() {
            if(root.elm != false) {
                if (i < root.max) {
                    i++;
                    root.elm.text(i);
                } else {
                    clearInterval(root.interval);
                }
            }
            this.interval = setInterval('root.runtTime()', 5);
        };
    };

    if($(document).ready(function() {
        var countUp= new time();
        countUp.max = 1526;
        countUp.elm = $("#elm");
        countUp.runTime();
    });
```

Comment: which line gets the error? the second one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because of the following line:

```
this.interval = setInterval('root.runtTime()', 5);
```

Because it's a string it [has to be evaluated as a global object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719758/difference-between-arguments-in-setinterval-calls).

Change to the following to ensure the same scope:

```
this.interval = setInterval(root.runtTime, 5);
```

Also there's a typo (`runtTime` should be `runTime`), so change to the following:

```
this.interval = setInterval(root.runTime, 5);
```

Finally you're using `setInterval` which will repeatedly call `root.runTime` every 5ms. Change to `setTimeout` if you wish to call this recursively:

```
this.interval = setTimeout(root.runTime, 5);
```

Alternatively set up the interval outside of your `runTime` function:

```
   root.runTime = function() {
        if(root.elm != false) {
            if (i < root.max) {
                i++;
                root.elm.text(i);
            } else {
                clearInterval(root.interval);
            }
        }
    };
    this.interval = setInterval(root.runTime, 5);
```

---

Also you don't need the `if` statement around `document.ready`. This is a callback function which is triggered when the DOM has loaded, and therefore doesn't require an if statement.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var countUp= new time();
    countUp.max = 1526;
    countUp.elm = $("#elm");
    countUp.runTime();
});
```

Comment: BTW `setInterval ` set an Interval so will call `root.runtTime`  n^2

Comment: He also doesn't need the if in the document.ready... this will throw the error as well as he didn't properly close the brackets..